# Не приходят данные запроса в google форму

Tags: html, google-forms

В попытках отправить данные с собственной формы и input'ами с именами соответствующих input'ов в google-форме(делал по примеру https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/#customize-google-form, отличие в том, что в новых формах hidden input'ы), пришел к тому, что в google-таблицу приходит лишь timestap, остальные же данные пусты, хотя запросом передаются.
Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfhpUYhaCbn-iMpHtlmrwGzBNze56lGaeCH0MGhymooKwfuGA/formResponse">
        <hr>
        <h3>Немного информации о Вас)</h3>

        <p>Ваш пол:</p>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="М" id="Mpol" name="entry.959163167">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Mpol">М</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="radio"  class="form-check-input" value="Ж" id="JPol" name="entry.959163167">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="JPol">Ж</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Ваш возраст:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="entry.1156004952">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="education">Ваше образованиe:</label>
            <input type="text" id="education" class="form-control" name="entry.363057680">
        </div>

        <hr>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Отправил данные post запросом прямиком в таблицу, где с помощью скрипта:

```
    // original from: http://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

// Usage
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Новая форма (Ответы)";

//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app 
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version' 
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously) 
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action 
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function

function doPost(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d//edit#gid=1502757433
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1HADODHrmOg8xWD9ScbWCjFt-YNZJgpjujsSP9XfPHHY');
    var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      "<form action='https://biblbrox-config.github.io/testingPage/success.html' method='get' id='foo'></form>" + 
      "<script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>");
//    return ContentService
//          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
//          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

данные записываются в таблицу.